# MYSQL: finding the similar and unique likes among friends

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Imagine we have two tables as follows:

1. **friend(uid1 int, uid2 int)**

   *this tables holds all the id's of the people who are friend with each other.*
2. **likes(uid, lid)**

   *this table holds the items liked (index by lid) by each user id*

**I would like to know, for each friend A and B, how many items they both liked versus how many unique items they liked in a combined manner.**

I am using MySQL so we don't have full join.

This seems like such a complex query to me. I think I got to some point to get some of these values, but I want to know how others would have done this:

Here is code to construct sample tables for **friend** and **likes**

```
create table friend (uid1 int, uid2 int);

insert into friend values
(1,2),
(2,1),
(1,3),
(2,3);

create table likes(uid int, lid int);

insert into likes values
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 5),
(3, 4);
```

and here is my implementation so far:

```
select r.uid1, r.uid2, 
    sum(case when r.lid1 is null then 0 else 1 end) as uniqueLike1, 
    sum(case when r.lid2 is null then 0 else 1 end) as uniqueLike2, 
    sum(case when r.lid1 is not null and r.lid2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) as uniqueLike1and2
from
(select f.uid1 as uid1, f.uid2 as uid2, l1.lid as lid1, l2.lid as lid2
from friend f join likes l1 on f.uid1 = l1.uid left join likes l2 on f.uid2=l2.uid and l1.lid = l2.lid
union
select ff.uid1 as uid1, ff.uid2 as uid2, ll2.lid as lid1, ll1.lid as lid2
from friend ff join likes ll1 on ff.uid2 = ll1.uid left join likes ll2 on ff.uid1=ll2.uid and ll1.lid = ll2.lid) r
group by r.uid1, r.uid2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a traditional approach.  I'm not even promising that it is efficient (particularly if users like a lot of things).  But, it has the merit of being relatively simple:

```
select f.uid1, f.uid2,
       count(distinct case when l1.lid = l2.lid then l1.lid end) as likes_in_common,
       (count(distinct l1.lid) - 
        count(distinct case when l1.lid = l2.lid then l1.lid end)
       ) as likes_only1,
       (count(distinct l2.lid) - 
        count(distinct case when l1.lid = l2.lid then l1.lid end)
       ) as likes_only2
from friend f left join
     likes l1
     on l1.uid = f.uid1 left join
     likes l2
     on l2.uid = f.uid2
group by f.uid1, f.uid2;
```

The idea is to count the number of items in common.  That is the first `count()` expression.  Then, the unique ones are given by subtraction.

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` is needed because the `FROM` clause generates a Cartesian product for all the likes for both users.